# What is the meaning of "down" here?

Tags: meaning

> Budget per campaign’s down almost forty percent.

I searched the meanings of [down](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/down) but Still I don't understand the sentence.

So could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text:

> ‘It’s not so bad,’ the Mother was saying to the Father. ‘There aren’t
> enough of us. Budget per campaign’s **down** almost forty percent. We’re
> in chronic conflict with the PR people. But otherwise, yes. It’s fine.

*The Klara and The Sun* by Kazuo Ishiguro

Comment: substitute reduced for down and that should explain it.

Comment: The second definition that you quoted (down adverb (LOWER LEVEL)) is the appropriate meaning.

Comment: Prices go ***up***, and they go ***down***, as do salaries, expenses and funds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage is in the dictionary link you sent.

> down adjective, adverb [not gradable] (WORSE)
> into a worse position or state:
> Michigan, down (by) (= losing by) ten points at the half, came back to win the football game.

As you can see, we sometimes say "down *by* [x]", or omit the word 'by' and just say "down [x]". It is implied that the number quoted is lower than, or has reduced by, some other measure that is not mentioned. In the dictionary example of a sports score, it can only mean that the team has ten points less than the other team.

In your example of "[the] budget per campaign’s down almost forty percent" would be assumed to mean that the budget is forty percent less than the previous budget, although that should not be assumed. Sometimes statistics can be deliberately misleading by measuring against a figure from 2, 5 or 10 years ago.